# Rally custom html to show all test cases in test sets associated with a release

Tags: rally, appsdk2

I'm searching for Rally custom html to show all test cases in test sets associated with a specific release. Along with each test case should be shown its most recent result - but only those results from any of the test sets associated with the specified release. If a test case has no result in any of the test sets associated with the release it should still be listed, and shown as having no result.

Because we run releases in parallel, I can't use iteration dates falling within release start and end dates as a way to identify which test sets and/or results are relevant to the release. This is the case in some of Rally's RQM toolkit examples.

Although it can be achieved by doing "Track - Release Status" and clicking Test Cases its too many clicks, and the testsets are many pages through the list of stories and defects and also that view can't be contained in a higher level dashboard.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks,

Andy

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example you may start with. This [AppSDK2](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/) app builds two grids: stories and test sets filtered by release. The Test Set gird shows associated test cases and test case status. The html source code can be copied to HTML section of a custom page in Rally. The js source file is in this GitHub [repo](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/stories-testsets-by-release/blob/master/src/App.js).

[image]

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Stories and TestSets by Release</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/2.0rc1/sdk.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            Rally.onReady(function () {
                Ext.define('CustomApp', {
                    extend: 'Rally.app.TimeboxScopedApp',
                    componentCls: 'app',
                    scopeType: 'release',

                    addContent: function() {
                        var panel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                            width: 1200,
                            layout: 'column',
                            itemId: 'parentPanel',
                            componentCls: 'panel',
                            items: [
                                {
                                    xtype: 'panel',
                                    title: 'Stories',
                                    itemId: 'childPanel1',
                                    columnWidth: 0.3
                                },
                                {
                                    xtype: 'panel',
                                    title: 'Test Sets with Test Cases',
                                    itemId: 'childPanel2',
                                    columnWidth: 0.7
                                }
                            ]
                        });
                        this.add(panel);
                        this._makeStore();
                    },

                   onScopeChange: function() {
                        console.log('onScopeChange');
                        this._makeStore();
                    },

                    _makeStore: function(){
                         var storyStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
                            model: 'UserStory',
                            fetch: ['FormattedID','Name'],
                            pageSize: 100,
                            autoLoad: true,
                            filters: [this.getContext().getTimeboxScope().getQueryFilter()],
                            listeners: {
                                load: this._onStoriesLoaded,
                                scope: this
                            }
                        }); 
                    },

                      _onStoriesLoaded: function(store, data){
                                var userStories = [];
                                Ext.Array.each(data, function(story) {
                                    var s  = {
                                        FormattedID: story.get('FormattedID'),
                                        _ref: story.get("_ref"),  
                                        Name: story.get('Name'),
                                    };
                                    userStories.push(s);
                                 });
                                this._createStoryGrid(userStories);
                    },
                    _createStoryGrid:function(stories){
                        var that = this;
                        var storyStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.custom.Store', {
                                data: stories,
                                pageSize: 100
                            });
                        if (!this.down('#storygrid')) {
                            this.down('#childPanel1').grid = this.down('#childPanel1').add({
                            xtype: 'rallygrid',
                            itemId: 'storygrid',
                            store: storyStore,
                            columnCfgs: [
                                {
                                   text: 'Formatted ID', dataIndex: 'FormattedID', xtype: 'templatecolumn',
                                    tpl: Ext.create('Rally.ui.renderer.template.FormattedIDTemplate')
                                },
                                {
                                    text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'Name',flex:2
                                }
                            ],
                            listeners: {
                                render: this._makeAnotherStore,
                                scope: this
                            }
                        });
                         }else{
                            this.down('#childPanel1').grid.reconfigure(storyStore);
                            this._makeAnotherStore(this);
                         }
                    },

                    _makeAnotherStore: function(){
                        Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
                                model: 'TestSet',
                                fetch: ['FormattedID', 'TestCases', 'TestCaseStatus'],  
                                pageSize: 100,
                                autoLoad: true,
                                filters: [this.getContext().getTimeboxScope().getQueryFilter()],
                                listeners: {
                                    load: this._onTestSetsLoaded,
                                    scope: this
                                }
                            }); 
                    },
                     _onTestSetsLoaded: function(store, data){
                        var testSets = [];
                        var pendingTestCases = data.length;
                         console.log(data.length);
                         if (data.length ===0) {
                            this._createTestSetGrid(testSets); 
                         }
                         Ext.Array.each(data, function(testset){ 
                            var ts  = {
                                FormattedID: testset.get('FormattedID'),   
                                _ref: testset.get('_ref'),  
                                TestCaseStatus: testset.get('TestCaseStatus'),
                                TestCaseCount: testset.get('TestCases').Count,
                                TestCases: []
                            };
                            var testCases = testset.getCollection('TestCases');
                            testCases.load({
                                                fetch: ['FormattedID'],
                                                callback: function(records, operation, success){
                                                    Ext.Array.each(records, function(testcase){
                                                        ts.TestCases.push({_ref: testcase.get('_ref'),
                                                                        FormattedID: testcase.get('FormattedID')
                                                                    });
                                                    }, this);
                                                    --pendingTestCases;
                                                    if (pendingTestCases === 0) {
                                                        this._createTestSetGrid(testSets);
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                scope: this
                                            });
                            testSets.push(ts);
                     },this);
                 },

                      _createTestSetGrid: function(testsets) {
                        var testSetStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.custom.Store', {
                                data: testsets,
                                pageSize: 100,  
                            });
                        if (!this.down('#testsetgrid')) {
                         this.down('#childPanel2').grid = this.down('#childPanel2').add({
                            xtype: 'rallygrid',
                            itemId: 'testsetgrid',
                            store: testSetStore,
                            columnCfgs: [
                                {
                                   text: 'Formatted ID', dataIndex: 'FormattedID', xtype: 'templatecolumn',
                                    tpl: Ext.create('Rally.ui.renderer.template.FormattedIDTemplate')
                                },
                                {
                                    text: 'Test Case Count', dataIndex: 'TestCaseCount',
                                },
                                {
                                    text: 'Test Case Status', dataIndex: 'TestCaseStatus',flex:1
                                },
                                {
                                    text: 'TestCases', dataIndex: 'TestCases',flex:1, 
                                    renderer: function(value) {
                                        var html = [];
                                        Ext.Array.each(value, function(testcase){
                                            html.push('<a href="' + Rally.nav.Manager.getDetailUrl(testcase) + '">' + testcase.FormattedID + '</a>')
                                        });
                                        return html.join(', ');
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        });
                         }else{
                            this.down('#childPanel2').grid.reconfigure(testSetStore);
                         }
                    }
    });

              Rally.launchApp('CustomApp', {
                    name:"Stories and TestSets by Release",
                    //parentRepos:""
                });

            });
        </script>

        <style type="text/css">
    .app {
         /* Add app styles here */
    }

    .panel{
        left: 15%
    }

        </style>

    </head>
    <body></body>
    </html>
```